# how i can forward the data in jTable

Tags: java, swing

when i want to forward jTextField to show the database  i can use the following code

```
try
{   
if ( rs.next( ) ) 
{
int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
  String id =Integer.toString(id_col);
  String firstname = rs.getString("FIRSTNAME");
  String lastname = rs.getString("LASTNAME");
  String job = rs.getString("JOBTITLE");

  textID.setText(id);
  textFirstName.setText(firstname);
  textLastName.setText(lastname);
  textJobTitle.setText(job);
}
else {
rs.previous( );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "End of File");
}
}
catch (SQLException err) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err.getMessage());
}

}
```

if i want to forward the data in jTable how i can do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the data from the database to a TableModel.

You can start by looking at [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for some ideas. The `TableFromDatabaseExample.java` example code may be the best place to start.